# How to post group of requests to 2 urls with aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have 2 URLs and 60k+ requests. Basically, I need to post every request to both URLs, then compare their responses, but not to wait for the response to post another request.

I've tried to do it with `aiohttp` and `asyncio`

```
import asyncio
import time
import aiohttp
import os

from aiofile import AIOFile

testURL = ""
prodURL = ""

directoryWithRequests = ''
directoryToWrite = ''

headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}

i = 1


async def fetch(session, url, reqeust):
    global i
    async with session.post(url=url, data=reqeust.encode('utf-8'), headers=headers) as response:
        if response.status != 200:
            async with AIOFile(directoryToWrite + str(i) + '.xml', 'w') as afp:
                await afp.write(reqeust)
                i += 1
        return await response.text()


async def fetch_all(session, urls, request):
    results = await asyncio.gather(*[asyncio.create_task(fetch(session, url, request)) for url in urls])
    return results


async def asynchronousRequests(requestBody):
    urls = [testURL, prodURL]
    global i
    with open(requestBody) as my_file:
        body = my_file.read()

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        htmls = await fetch_all(session, urls, body)
        # some conditions

async def asynchronous():
    try:
        start = time.time()
        futures = [asynchronousRequests(directoryWithRequests + i) for i in os.listdir(directoryWithRequests)]
        for future in asyncio.as_completed(futures):
            result = await future

        print("Process took: {:.2f} seconds".format(time.time() - start))

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        # AsyncronTest
        ioloop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
        ioloop.run_until_complete(asynchronous())
        ioloop.close()
        if i == 1:
            print('Regress is OK')
        else:
            print('Number of requests to check = {}'.format(i))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I believe that the code above works, but it creates N futures, where the N  equals to the number of request files. This brings to sort of ddos because the server can't response to that number of requests at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Found suitable solution. Basically it's just 2 async tasks:

```
tasks = [
                postRequest(testURL, client, body),
                postRequest(prodURL, client, body)
            ]
await asyncio.wait(tasks)
```

It's not the same performance as the code in the question with afortable number of requests, but as least it doesn't ddos the server that much.